# Как получить id пользователя

Tags: php, mysql

Как получить id пользователя, который вошел под своим логином и паролем?
Вместо "/?mode=auth"

```
   //Сбрасываем параметры
   header('Location:'. BEZ_HOST .'/?mode=auth');
```

Вот полный скрипт авторизации

```
<?php
 /*
 * Обработчик формы авторизации
 */

 //Если нажата кнопка то обрабатываем данные
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    if(empty($_POST['email']))
        $err[] = 'Не введен Логин';

    if(empty($_POST['pass']))
        $err[] = 'Не введен Пароль';

    //Проверяем наличие ошибок и выводим пользователю
    if(count($err) > 0)
        echo showErrorMessage($err);
    else
    {
        //Создаем запрос на выборку из базы данных для проверки подлиности пользователя
        $sql = 'SELECT * 
                FROM `'. BEZ_DBPREFIX .'reg`
                WHERE `login` = "'. escape_str($_POST['email']) .'"';
        $res = mysqlQuery($sql);

        //Если логин совподает, проверяем пароль
        if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)
        {
            //Получаем данные из таблицы
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

            if(md5(md5($_POST['pass']).$row['salt']) == $row['pass'])
            {   
                $_SESSION['user'] = true;

                //Сбрасываем параметры
                header('Location:'. BEZ_HOST .'/?mode=auth');
                exit;
            }
            else
                echo showErrorMessage('Неверный пароль!');
        }
        else
            echo showErrorMessage('Логин <b>'. $_POST['email'] .'</b> не найден!');
    }

 }

?>
```

Надеюсь на помощь, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

После того, как проверили пароль, можно записать id пользователя в сессию:

```
$_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
```